# Can't see named range for table when worksheet is hidden

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to access a named range via VBA:

```
Set rng = selectionSht.Parent.Names(rangeName).RefersToRange
```

However, this particular named range is mapped to a table on a hidden worksheet.  When the worksheet is hidden, the named range disappears from the list of named ranges shown when I go to `Formulas->Name Manager`, but it reappears in the list when I unhide the sheet.  This does not happen to other named ranges that refer to static ranges--it seems to only be an issue for named ranges that correspond to tables.

When the sheet is hidden, the above line of VBA code returns:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

How can I make this named range readable when the sheet is hidden?

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think you can. Some VBA functions only work on what is visible. I.E. if you had a cell with width set to 0, it treats it as hidden and as something you can't access. What you may want to do is to put screen updating = false, show the hidden worksheet, do what you need to with the named range, make the worksheet hidden again, and then turn on screen updating = true. From the perspective of the user, they still never see the hidden worksheet

Comment: @EricF, that sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly do what you want. In VBA, if a cell is not visible to the user, then VBA also can't see it. For example if you set a cell's width to 0, VBA treats that as not visible and therefore you can't access it, similar to what you have above.

The way you can achieve a task while keeping a cell / row / column hidden is to do the following:

1. Turn `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`
2. `.Show` the hidden area that you are referrencing
3. Perform whatever operation you need to do to the given cells
4. `.Hide` the area that you worked on
5. Turn `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` back on.

From the user's standpoint since screenupdating was off, the cell / row / column never was shown but you can still achieve your task.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to other answer, you CAN access ranges on hidden sheets. You just have to reference them properly. It's unnecessary to use `RefersToRange` and `Names`.

Reference the range as a range, not a name. Use a fully-qualified name, starting with the workbook.

```
Set rng = Workbooks("BookName").Sheets("SheetName").Range("RangeName")
```

This example uses VBA object naming (instead of Excel naming), and assumes you've renamed the VBAProject:

```
Set rng = MyProject.Sheet1.Range("rangename")
```

Suggestion, don't call a hidden sheet "selectionSht". "Selection" implies visible.